# Ruby string char chunking

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string "wwwggfffw" and want to break it up into an array as follows:

```
  ["www", "gg", "fff", "w"]
```

Is there a way to do this with regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"wwwggfffw".scan(/((.)\2*)/).map(&:first)
```

`scan` is a little funny, as it will return either the match or the subgroups depending on whether there are subgroups; we need to use subgroups to ensure repetition of the same character (`(.)\1`), but we'd prefer it if it returned the whole match and not just the repeated letter. So we need to make the whole match into a subgroup so it will be captured, and in the end we need to extract just the match (without the other subgroup), which we do with `.map(&:first)`.

EDIT to explain the regexp `((.)\2*)` itself:

```
(   start group #1, consisting of
(     start group #2, consisting of
.       any one character
)       and nothing else
\2    followed by the content of the group #2
*       repeated any number of times (including zero)
)     and nothing else.
```

So in `wwwggfffw`, `(.)` captures `w` into group #2; then `\2*` captures any additional number of `w`. This makes group #1 capture `www`.

Comment: Im a little confused about the syntax of this back reference. Here the \2 means the second group of parenthesis, but the \2 is within the second group of parenthesis, how can that work? What does * mean here?

Comment: `\2` is not in the second group; groups are counted by the position of the *opening* parenthesis. I edited in a detailed explanation of the regexp.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [back references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), something like

```
'wwwggfffw'.scan(/((.)\2*)/).map{ |s| s[0] }
```

will work

Comment: It works! Could you explain a bit about the syntax of this particular regex?

Comment: Sure, the first thing we have is the `.`. This says match any character. We then put it in parentheses `(.)` which is saying that we want a reference group. We then use the `\2*` as a back reference which is saying "match the second matching group as many times as possible". Then we wrap the whole thing in another set of parentheses so that we can extract the full expression.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that's not using regex but works well:

```
def chunk(str)
  chars = str.chars

  chars.inject([chars.shift]) do |arr, char|
    if arr[-1].include?(char)
      arr[-1] << char
    else
      arr << char
    end

    arr
  end
end
```

In my benchmarks it's faster than the regex answers here (with the example string you gave, at least).

Answer (score 0):

Another non-regex solution, this one using [Enumerable#slice_when](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when), which made its debut in Ruby v.2.2:

```
str.each_char.slice_when { |a,b| a!=b }.map(&:join)
  #=> ["www", "gg", "fff", "w"]
```

Another option is:

```
str.scan(Regexp.new(str.squeeze.each_char.map { |c| "(#{c}+)" }.join)).first
  #=> ["www", "gg", "fff", "w"]
```

Here the steps are as follows

```
s = str.squeeze
  #=> "wgfw" 
a = s.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "wgfw":each_char>
```

This enumerator generates the following elements:

```
a.to_a
  #=> ["w", "g", "f", "w"]
```

Continuing

```
b = a.map { |c| "(#{c}+)" }
  #=> ["(w+)", "(g+)", "(f+)", "(w+)"] 
c = b.join
  #=> "(w+)(g+)(f+)(w+)" 
r = Regexp.new(c)
  #=> /(w+)(g+)(f+)(w+)/ 
d = str.scan(r)
  #=> [["www", "gg", "fff", "w"]] 
d.first
  #=> ["www", "gg", "fff", "w"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more way of doing it without a regex:

```
'wwwggfffw'.chars.chunk(&:itself).map{ |s| s[1].join }
# => ["www", "gg", "fff", "w"]
```

Comment: I am not familiar with 'itself' here, could you explain?

Comment: `chunk(&:itself)` has the same effect as `chunk { |e| e }`. [Object#itself](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) made its debut in Ruby v.2.2.